# Why when opening index.html javadoc file generated in Eclipse results in opening in one of the class html file?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, javadoc

I am just starting learning javadoc, and after generating javadoc files, index.html doesn't work as it supposed to, and it happens to all of my java project. Is it because of the Eclipse settings? I couldn't find answers anywhere. Please help, thank you

I tried regenerating javadoc files and it didn't work

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Generated by javadoc (17) on Thu Jan 18 18:21:09 EST 2024 -->
<title>Generated Documentation (Untitled)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="dc.created" content="2024-01-18">
<meta name="description" content="index redirect">
<meta name="generator" content="javadoc/IndexRedirectWriter">
<link rel="canonical" href="ButtonCounter.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" title="Style">
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace('ButtonCounter.html')</script>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;ButtonCounter.html">
</noscript>
</head>
<body class="index-redirect-page">
<main role="main">
<noscript>
<p>JavaScript is disabled on your browser.</p>
</noscript>
<p><a href="ButtonCounter.html">ButtonCounter.html</a></p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated index.html attempts to redirect to ButtonCounter.html.

Several things you can do to fix what is causing the error are, first check if `ButtonCounter.html` exists in the output directory of the javadoc, because if it does not exist there the redirection fails.

See if the javadoc generation is giving any errors and if so, where and why.

Also in Eclipse you can check how the javadoc is configured, Right click on your project, go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Javadoc Location and make sure it is configured correctly.

And the old reliable, clean and rebuild project